# How do I move files from one user account to another on the same computer?

Tags: permissions

I went into file system/home and tried to move files from one user account to another. it refused to move anything because it said I do not have permission. I am the administrator and both accounts are set that way.

Comment: You're admin of YOUR own account, to move files to another user folder use `gksu nautilus`.

Answer (score 8):

Or use sudo

```
sudo cp source destination
sudo chown user:user file
sudo chmod permissions file
```

You may need to use that second command(s) to set permissions depending on what you moved where and what access you need.

See also

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

Answer (score 4):

Run these commands in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gksu

gksu nautilus
```

A file manager will open. Do not close the terminal in the background, as the terminal is giving you admin permissions. Now you have a file manager as an admin, and you may copy/move/delete whatever you like.

Answer (score 2):

A `chown` command example for this might be:

```
chown -R user:usergroup *
```

- The `-R` is for recursive change of ownership through subdirectories.
- `user` is the name of the user account to which you wish to assign ownership of the files.
- `usergroup` is the user's primary group (usually the same as the user)
- The `*` is an expression indicating all files.

Comment: `*` doesn't actually match all files in the current directory. Specifically, it doesn't match files whose names start with a `.` character.